# Change cursor to Pointer in TableCalendar for flutter web

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web

I used `table_calendar: ^3.0.8` for the calendar in my flutter web application. But when we click on a date instead of the pointer it shows the cursor.[image]

Is it possible to change the cursor to a pointer?

Table calendar code

```
   TableCalendar(

                                          eventLoader: (day) {
                                            return   controller.getEventsListResponse2.value.data!.rows!.where((event) => isSameDay(DateTime.parse(event.eventStartDateTime.toString()),day)).toList();
                                          },

                                        onDaySelected: (date,events,) {

                                          setState(() {
                                            _selectedDay = date;
                                            _focusedDay = events;
                                          });


                                          controller.eventDetails.value =
                                              controller.getEventsListResponse2.value.data!.rows!
                                                  .where((event) =>
                                                  isSameDay(DateTime.parse(event.eventStartDateTime.toString()),events)).toList();
                            

                                          selectedDayPredicate: (day) =>
                                              isSameDay(_selectedDay, day),
                                          headerStyle: HeaderStyle(
                                            headerPadding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 20,left: 16),
                                              leftChevronVisible:false,
                                              rightChevronVisible: false,
                                              titleCentered: false,
                                              formatButtonVisible: false,
                                           

                                          ),
                                calendarStyle: CalendarStyle(
                                

                                 
                                
                                selectedDecoration: BoxDecoration(


                                    //color: Colors.white,
                                      border: Border.all(
                                          color:  AppColors.primaryColor,
                                        width: 2
                                      ),
                                      //color:Color(0xff513E81),
                                      shape: BoxShape.rectangle),
                                ),


                                          firstDay: DateTime(2020, 1), lastDay: DateTime(2030, 12), focusedDay: _focusedDay
```

,
)

In normal case, I wrap Gesturedetector with MOuseRegion.But here there is no gesture detector.

Answer (score 0):

Issue resolved.
I Wrapped TableCalendar with MouseRegion.

```
MouseRegion(
            cursor: SystemMouseCursors.click,
             child: TableCalendar()
)
```